# How to automatically change names of event handlers for a control after renaming it?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Let's say there's a Windows Forms App and there's a button called `button1`.

I double click on a button, it creates an event handler called `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`. Then I rename this button from `button1` to `myButton`.

I would like to make IDE to rename all event handlers for this button from `button1_` to `myButton_` accordingly and also rename all references it can find in a solution to these event handlers.

I understand it can probably introduce problems in some specific cases, but that's what I currently do manually: rename event handler in the designer, it creates new handler in the code, then delete empty handler and rename original handler. And repeat for every handler for this control.

I would like to automate it with a single shortcut "Rename all event handlers and references to these event handlers for this control".

I hope it makes sense what I want to achiever here. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Partial solution can also be found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454931/in-c-how-can-you-easily-change-the-name-of-an-event-handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you have to do is rename the event handler in the code.

- In Form1.cs, find `button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)`
- Place your cursor in the method name and press <kbd>F2</kbd> (or Edit > Refactor > Rename...)
- Highlight `button1` and change it to `myButton`.

This will update the reference on the form and all other places in the code which reference the event handler.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that's what I've started doing yesterday after I asked this question.

Comment: But you see, it is still mostly manual and semi-automatic at best, because I have to rename every event handler individually. Imagine if I have 20 event handlers for 1 control and I rename this control. Then I have to manually refactor 20 event handlers of this control. What I'm trying to achieve here is to be able to refactor the whole control. Something like find declaration of a control in `Form1.Designer.cs` `private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;`, highlight `button1`, RMB, refactor > rename, rename the control and so it would rename all of its event handlers as well accordingly.

Comment: I wish what you want is possible. I don't know a way. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3454931/2908576) is asking that specific scenario. It has four answers, but none of them actually solve having the event handlers renamed when you rename the control. I'm sure you could write an extension to do this, but it would be fragile and require a very specific naming convention to be followed.

Comment: It's a smidgen ironic that Delphi, C#'s predecessor had this feature at the turn of the century in Delphi 7 already.